# sql getting sum of calculated columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I get the sum of `TotalAmount` as single value for example

```
Product Name UnitPrice  Quantity    Discount%      Amount     SharingCost%  ShippingCost    CustomsCost  TotalAmount
pro1        250.00      12          10.00           3000.00   75             375.00         0.00             3075.00
pro2        100.00      10          10.00           1000.00   25             125.00         125.00           1025.00
```

from the above sample data sum of `TotalAmount`is 4100.00.

How can I get sum value which is 4100.00 in single column for specific Purchase_ID

**Note**

Parent table is `Stock_Purchase`

Child table is `Stock_Purchase_Details`

**Query**

```
SELECT
  S.Product_Name,
  SPD.*,
  Sp.Delivery_Status,
  CONVERT(decimal(10, 2), (SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice)) Amount,
  CONVERT(int, (SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) / (SUM(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) OVER ()) * 100) [Cost%],
  CAST((SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) / (SUM(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) OVER ()) * Sp.Shipping_Cost AS decimal(10, 2)) AS [ShippingCost],
  CAST((SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) / (SUM(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) OVER ()) * Sp.Customs_Cost AS decimal(10, 2)) AS [CustomsCost],
  CAST((SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) / (SUM(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) OVER ()) * Sp.Shipping_Cost + (SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) / (SUM(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) OVER ()) * Sp.Customs_Cost + SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice - (SPD.Discount / 100) * SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice AS decimal(10, 2)) AS [TotalAmount]
FROM dbo.Stock_Purchase SP
INNER JOIN dbo.Stock_Purchase_Details SPD
  ON SP.Purchase_ID = SPD.Purchase_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Store S
  ON SPD.Pro_ID = S.Pro_ID
WHERE SPD.Purchase_ID = '1'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try naming that query, and then using the column with `PARTITION BY` in an OVER clause.

```
WITH MyCTE AS (
SELECT
  S.Product_Name,
    SPD.*,
    Sp.Delivery_Status,
  CONVERT(decimal(10, 2), (SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice)) Amount,
  CONVERT(int, (SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) / (SUM(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) OVER ()) * 100) [Cost%],
  CAST((SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) / (SUM(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) OVER ()) * Sp.Shipping_Cost AS decimal(10, 2)) AS [ShippingCost],
  CAST((SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) / (SUM(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) OVER ()) * Sp.Customs_Cost AS decimal(10, 2)) AS [CustomsCost],
  CAST((SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) / (SUM(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) OVER ()) * Sp.Shipping_Cost + (SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) / (SUM(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) OVER ()) * Sp.Customs_Cost + SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice - (SPD.Discount / 100) * SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice AS decimal(10, 2)) AS [TotalAmount]
FROM dbo.Stock_Purchase SP
INNER JOIN dbo.Stock_Purchase_Details SPD
  ON SP.Purchase_ID = SPD.Purchase_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Store S
  ON SPD.Pro_ID = S.Pro_ID
)
SELECT *, SUM(TotalAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY Purchase_ID)
FROM MyCTE;
```

But also, you may like to consider using APPLY to make this a lot simpler. Read http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2011/12/13/a-t-sql-tip-working-calculations/ for more info on this.